Is it possible to get an S3 object, manipulate the file using PHP, then place it back into the S3 bucket without saving anything on the server?
I am trying to grab an image I have stored out in a S3 bucket, and then either resize or rotate the image, and then load it back into my S3 bucket at it's original spot.
I am able to grab the image and get the image content this way:
$result = $s3->getObject(awsBucket, $key);
$content = $result->body;

This will output something like:
����JFIF``��>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), default quality ��C    $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342��C  2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222����"�� ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������� ���w!1AQaq"2�B���� #3R�br�...

I am using SimpleImage V2.5.1 to manipulate the images (https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage/tree/2.5.1)
$degrees = 90;
$image = new SimpleImage();
$output = $image->load($content)->rotate($degrees)->output('jpg');
$s3->putObject($output, awsBucket, $key, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ, $headers = array(), 'image/jpg');

My file does not appear to be overwritten with a rotated version, as SimpleImage sees it as an invalid image.
If I load the object URL in like this:
$image->load(https://mys3bucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ . $key)->rotate($degrees)->output('jpg');

Then the image is loaded and rotated as expected, but I am unable to use that in my putObject method to save the file.
Does anyone have any thoughts on the best approach for this?

the load() function takes a filename, not file content. However, you can base64 encode your data and then use load_base64() (which, amusingly, has the wrong argument name in its documentation)

Thanks for the detals @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - I may have been incorrect with the version of our SimpleImage. It looks like its an older version that has a different load method. It looks more like this version. I can grab an the image URL from S3 and rotate it using this route. Just can't figure out how to save the edited version.

in that case please remember to not just say that in a comment but to [edit] your post so it mentions the correct version you're using. Can you confirm that the output function for the version you're using actually outputs the expected data?
